# I can not run nicEditor at Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

Here is code, doesn't seem to an error

```
extends ../layout

block content

  script(type='text/javascript', language='javascript', src='/js/nicEdit.js')

  script bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() })

  form(role='form', method='post', action='/blogs')
      legend
      div.form-group
        textarea(name='area1')
        button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
        button.btn.btn-default(type='reset') Clear
        a.btn.btn-default(href='/blogs/admin') Back
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, like the [Jade Reference](http://jade-lang.com/) shows:

```
script(type='text/javascript', language='javascript', src='/js/nicEdit.js').
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
```

This should look like this example from [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/demos.php) in HTML.

Comment: If it's html5, you can drop the `type` and `language` on the script tag